# How do you find the Taylor series and radius of convergence for $\sqrt{1-x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

$f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ at $x_{0}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$

Hi, I'm having difficulties finding any sort of patterns and have been quite exhausted by differentiating this function multiple times. My assignment was to find the 3rd order Taylor Polynomial for the series, but another thing I want to do with it is determine the radius of convergence for this function.

This is giving me a great pain, since I'm not sure of how to do this, I know that I might be able to rewrite it as a power series and use the ratio test, but even that seems a pain.

I'm only in high school, so my knowledge is mostly from self study. Is this completely out of my scope?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, thanks for the message. I added context and my work and thoughts on the problem to try and uphold the quality standards of the site.

Comment: See [Newtons Generalized Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem).

Comment: It would be good to list out your calculations.  That way we can check your work.

Comment: The fastest way to find the third degree Taylor polynomial is to start taking derivatives.  $f(x)\approx f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + f''(a)(x-a)^2+ f'''(a)(x-a)^3.$  At this point, you might spot a pattern to guess at what the entire series is going to look like.  However, we see that the function does not map to the real numbers for values of $x > 1$ and since your polynomial does, you are clearly diverging at this point and it will give you and upper bound for the radius of convergence.

Comment: Sorry. $f(x)\approx f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac {f''(a)(x-a)^2}{2}+ \frac {f'''(a)(x-a)^3}{3!}.$

Comment: At some point you will hopefully study complex analysis and learn that the radius of convergence of the power series about $ \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}$ is the distance between this point and the singularity of the function which is closest to it (there are two algebraic singularities at $1$ and $-1$). Thus, the radius of convergence is $\left| {1 - \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}} \right| = 1 - \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

More than often, when $x_0 \neq 0$, it is a good practice to let $x=y+x_0$ and work around $y=0$. Doing it for your case
$$\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{2}y -y^2}=\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{1-2 \sqrt{2} y-2 y^2 }$$ Now, let $t=2 \sqrt{2} y+2 y^2$ ; use the binomial theorem for $\sqrt{1-t}$ (you do not need many terms). When done, replace $t$ by it definition; expand a little bit to have the series in terms of $y$ and replace $y$ by $ \left(x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$.

Notice that I did not use any derivative.